# Type a function that takes a key and value that match an object type, and then use them

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an object type, and I want to have a function that accepts a `key` from that object type, and a `value` that required to be the type of the property that corresponds to `key`.

I got this *mostly* working, until you actually use the values, and flow then forgets that they have been required to match up.

```
// @flow

type Obj = {
  str: string,
  num: number,
}

const obj: Obj = {
  str: '',
  num: 0,
}

function foo<KEY: $Keys<Obj>>(
  key: KEY,
  value: $ElementType<Obj, KEY>
) {
  obj[key] = value
  //         ^ Cannot assign `value` to `obj[key]` because string [1]
  //           is incompatible with number [2].
}

// Good
foo('str', 'good')
foo('num', 123)

// Bad
foo('str', 456) // ERROR: as expected.
foo('num', 'bad') // ERROR: as expected.
```

[Try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQEYBWoAvKAN6KigDOKATgFy0MCWAdgOYA0Vo7AVwC2zQUPxZ6vAL7IAxrHZ1QsIswLEylanSagA5Pt7UxzAAwy+iSAPZyUrRaEixYAHgDSAUQCazACQeWGg0bhoAfOEAFHwA1sHM3j7GoABuAIbQAlgBXtBYQljsKAAqmFhhRNygSeGIAJQUfKqEANrxaAC6pGmZ2YiyiCCgAOKuACbWrlH6ukYGnBP69VOwM2LzAIwATADMK0NgAEIAggAihy5rswzzACwArABsKyBX68Lz+vjp48tAA)

How do I let flow know this is actually just fine, because it *just* validated that key and value types match up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If to make a type of the generic more loose (annotate type of `KEY` as `string`) it will work.

```
type Obj = {
  str: string,
  num: number,
}

const obj: Obj = {
  str: '',
  num: 0,
}

function foo<KEY: string>(
  key: KEY,
  value: $ElementType<Obj, KEY>
) {
  obj[key] = value
}

// Good
foo('str', 'good')
foo('num', 123)

// BAD
//foo('str', 456)
//foo('num', 'bad')
```

At the same time, there will remain check for `key` argument be one of the keys from the `Obj` as otherwise `value` will be not able to get it type `$ElementType<Obj, KEY>`.

Check it here: [flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQEYBWoAvKAN6KigDOKATgFy0MCWAdgOYA0Vo7AVwC2zQUPxZ6vAL7IAxrHZ1QsIswLEylanSagA5Pt7UxzAAwy+iSAPZyUrRaEixYAHgDSAUQCazXRycAHwAFHwA1lhozN4+xqAAbgCG0AJYzAAkXtBYQljsKAAqmFhuGtygsUGIAJQUfKqEANqRaAC6pIkpaYiyiCCgAOKuACbWriH6ukYGnKP6NeOwk2IzAIwATADMi-1gAEIAggAiey7LUwwzACwArABsiyDnK8Iz+vhJIwtAA)

Comment: Thank you. A typical case of me trying harder than I have to.